# Android Studio search in file not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, search

in Android Studio, my search inside a file is not working well. Let's say I have a variable `recyclerView` then when I use `Cmd + F and rec` then it doesn't show up any results. But if I type `recyclerView` then it will show up the results, which is annoying to work with?

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: see if "Words" is not checked

Answer (score 0):

Remove Match case, words, regex check mark

Answer (score 0):

You have to check few things.

1. Is your project opened correctly in android studio. with all the packages.
   2.Check is there any search filter applied near your search box.
   ex:tic on Word or Match Case

Note: Try around little bit before Jump into asking a question.